# How do I open an Explorer window in a given directory from cmd.exe?

Tags: windows, scripting, cmd

I see how to launch [many other programs](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-run-commands.html) from a batch file, but I can't find a command like [`open`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/open.1.html) on Mac OS X.  Does such a tool exist on Windows?  Powershell, or a Windows API call from an executable would also work.

Or, put another way, how can I invoke Windows default "Open" handler for a file from a batch file or powershell script?

Comment: `start .`. In Linux the equivalent is `xdg-open .`

Comment: This is the answer you are looking for > `use start . `

Comment: Why was this marked off-topic? I think it is a valid programming question. Maybe rephrased as "how do I invoke the operating system default 'open' handler for a file from a shell script on windows" might make this more clear?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In Windows you can open Explorer with the following command:

```
C:\Users\Leniel>start %windir%\explorer.exe
```

If you want it to open a specific folder, do this for example:

```
C:\Users\Leniel>start %windir%\explorer.exe "C:\Users\Leniel\Desktop"
```

Comment: You can usually omit the explorer entirely: `start "c:\mydir"`

Comment: Also when launching a GUI program `start` is entirely unneeded. Furthermore, `explorer` is in the `%PATH%`, so `explorer someDir` suffices in any case.

Comment: @mandrill: That would launch another console window with `c:\mydir` as its title ;-)

Comment: Note that it is important to use "start" rather than invoking "explorer.exe" directly. Invoking it directly creates a new "explorer.exe" process (with associated memory) rather than opening a new window within the existing Explorer process.

Answer (score 33):

The direct equivalent of OS X's `open` is `start` in `cmd`.

```
start foo.txt
```

would launch Notepad (or whatever text editor you're using),

```
start http://example.com
```

would launch your browser,

```
start \someDirectory
```

will launch Explorer, etc.

Care has to be taken with arguments in quotes, as `start` will interpret the first quoted argument as the window title to use, so something like

```
start "C:\Users\Me\Folder with spaces\somedocument.docx"
```

will not work as intended. Instead prepend an empty quoted argument in that case:

```
start "" "C:\Users\Me\Folder with spaces\somedocument.docx"
```

Note that `start` isn't a separate program but a shell-builtin. So to invoke this from an external program you have to use something like

```
cmd /c start ...
```

The equivalent in PowerShell is either `Start-Process` or `Invoke-Item`. The latter is probably better suited for this task.

```
Invoke-Item foo.txt  # launches your text editor with foo.txt
Invoke-Item .        # starts Explorer in the current directory
```

As for the Windows API, you're looking for [`ShellExecute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762153(VS.85).aspx) with the `open` verb.

Comment: "start . " opens the current directory in the explorer

Answer (score 23):

You can just try

```
start .
```

This will open file explorer directly with the current directory path.

Comment: This is perfect answer :)

Comment: Only six keys touched.  Fast.

Answer (score 3):

"explorer.exe ." worked for me.

```
explorer.exe .
```

IMO - As we need to open "Windows Explorer" from cmd prompt, "explorer.exe ." is easy to remember.

Comment: This also works from inside Jupyter Notebook if you spawn out by typing "!explorer.exe ." although it opens the Explorer window UNDER the Jupyter NB.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this syntax:

```
explorer.exe folder_path
```

example:

```
explorer.exe D:\Movies
```

Answer (score 1):

You can open any folder in explorer using simply

```
explorer <directory path>
```

Answer (score 0):

How about (you don't need the `.exe` at the end)

```
explorer .
```

It will open the current window